# getting error while trying to send email

Tags: java, android

My code is...

```
public class AndroidEmailActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText edittextEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_address);
        final EditText edittextEmailSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_subject);
        final EditText edittextEmailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_text);
        Button buttonSendEmail_intent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendemail_intent);

        buttonSendEmail_intent.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String emailAddress = edittextEmailAddress.getText().toString();
                String emailSubject = edittextEmailSubject.getText().toString();
                String emailText = edittextEmailText.getText().toString();

                String emailAddressList[] = { emailAddress };

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("plain/text");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddressList);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Choice App t send email:"));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting error in the console window

```
[2011-10-18 12:43:54 - AndroidEmail] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-10-18 12:43:54 - AndroidEmail] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-10-18 12:43:54 - AndroidEmail] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.android.email' in a shell.
[2011-10-18 12:43:54 - AndroidEmail] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of this [thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887436/re-installation-failed-due-to-different-application-signatures

Comment: It simply says that your app is already installed on phone.Simply uninstall your app and then reinstall it.
or The package name you have used for your is already used by another app on your phone.

Comment: Have you tried the presented solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this error occurs because, application already install in the device from another computer . To overcome this problem first you need to uninstall the application and then try to install new application.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you are trying to run the application on a device which already have the same application created using a different keychain key. Please uninstall the application from the device / simulator and run it again. It will work.