# different application signatures error?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-installation failed due to different application signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887436/re-installation-failed-due-to-different-application-signatures)

when I try to run an app on my device, eclipse tells me the following:

Re-installation failed due different application signatures.

how to fix such an error?

Comment: delete the old one first (uninstall it )

Comment: and why not google/search on SO before posting?

Comment: I typically encounter this when attempting to run one of my apps from my Eclipse development environment when I've already installed the signed and exported APK on the device (or vice-versa). As others have said, the solution is to uninstall the old one first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first uninstall the application *(that has the old signature)* -- and, then, install the one with the new signature.

Note: actually, this is one of the reason why there is a security system like these signatures: it makes sure no user will think he's updating an application, when he is actually replacing it by another one, possibly fake *(as, in theory, only the real original author has the ability to sign with his own signature)*

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the old one using `adb uninstall name.of.app`