# android app install:Re-installation failed due to different application signatures

Tags: android

I build a app at one PC and then copy to another, then I run my device, tip:

```
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
```

actually, I did not sign app . unfortunately this apk I have send to my user and them update it automatically (app check version and then download and call to install), so them failed to install when update.

my questions:

1. I did not sign apk, but between the two computers, them sign automatically?
2. how to fix it when I copy code between PCs?

---

I have done following this post:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887436/re-installation-failed-due-to-different-application-signatures)

Answer (score 0):

copy debug keystore of one pc in to other will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Go to `C:\Users\yourName\` in your first computer and copy either the whole `.android` directory (recommended), or copy the `debug.keystore` file in the `.android` directory, onto the second computer in the same place as the first computer.

   That, or you can just uninstall your app on your phone, and then running it again from the second computer will work fine.

*Note*: Eclipse may not be targeting the correct path to your `debug.keystore` file (you may have put it in the wrong place, or something else happened). In that case, you would have to change that in Eclipse preferences:

Window --> Preferences --> Android --> Build

Then, look at the **default debug keystore**. Perhaps, if it's not pointing in the right place, use the **custom debug keystore** to point it in the right place.