# Re-installation failed due to different application signatures

Tags: android, eclipse, build-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the app signature change in Android after a classpath change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458931/why-does-the-app-signature-change-in-android-after-a-classpath-change)

I started getting errors in my Eclipse Workspace for several but not all of my projects.  I noticed is was the oldest projects.  I found help for the error, and built my own debug.keystore and changed the java build path to that folder.

Now when I try to run any of the projects in an emulator I get this error:

```
[2011-04-19 10:11:20 - enga] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-04-19 10:11:20 - enga] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-04-19 10:11:20 - enga] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.engatest' in a shell.
[2011-04-19 10:11:20 - enga] Launch canceled!
```

I tried removing the application from the menu in the emulator, got through the motions and drag it to the trash but it doesn't get removed.

I tried running in terminal: `adb uninstall com.dwclogic.engatest`
but the command wasn't found, adb probably not setup globally on my mac.  I am new to the Mac and am unsure how to get the execute path for this fixed but that's an whole other issue.

where do I try running this command?  Is there any other ways to fix this problem.

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings -> Applications then selecting the app then using Uninstall?

Answer (score 11):

1. You can remove an app in your emulator via Settings->Applications->manage Applications. There you can see a list of all installed apps. If you then click on the app you want to uninstall, a screen opens, with an uninstall option.
2. A second option for uninstall is the use of "adb uninstall". adb is a command line tool which is located under the Android SDK folder. You can find it there in a folder called "platform-tools". So you have to navigation to your SDK installation and use a terminal window to run adb there.

Dragging an icon onto the trash does not uninstall an app. It only removes it's icon from the home screen.

Comment: I made two "totally" separated apps, although the second app is greatly copied from the first app .. when the first app is installed I can't run the second app on my S4 ? what should I do to run both apps in the same device ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I get that error when my physical device is hooked up in my PC's USB port. If yours is plugged in try to unplug it

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Application -> Manage Application -> "tab on your application" -> uninstall

Run your application from Eclipse again and it'll definitely work for you :)