# "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures" - possible to override?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am developing my app on two PCs so obviously I get the error in Eclipse "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures" when trying to deploy on the physical device which has a copy of the app from the other machine.

My question is: is it possible to override this, meaning to deploy the app DESPITE different signatures?

The reason is that my app has a database which I don't want to wipe, because I am fixing a bug relating to it. Is there a quick fix that doesn't require uninstalling the app/copying the keyrstore file between the PCs ? Bet there isn't, but just asking. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the app signature change in Android after a classpath change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458931/why-does-the-app-signature-change-in-android-after-a-classpath-change)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NO, there is no way to override it. [From the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html):

> When the system is installing an update to an application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly, including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows the update.

One way to work around this will be to try to sign the apps on both machines with the same keystore. If you are using Eclipse,

1. Go to Preferences -> Android -> Build
   There you should find the path to the 'Default debug keystore'. (usually something like /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore.
2. Copy this file to the new machine.
3. Inside Eclipse on the new machine, open Preferences -> Android -> Build
4. Enter the path to the file in the field 'Custom debug keystore'
5. Save and then you can run your app and have it signed with the same key.

Good luck

### UPDATE:

It is now possible to configure your signing key in Gradle (which will be used by Android Studio) and include your debug key in source control. Just add the key to your project folder and then add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../debug.keystore")
        }
    }
```

And also add this under build types:

```
buildTypes {        
    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: is it possible to override this, meaning to deploy the app DESPITE different signatures?

Option #1: Uninstall the app, then reinstall.

Option #2: Synchronize your `debug.keystore` files between the two machines, so you are signing with the same key in both places.

> Is there a quick fix that doesn't require uninstalling the app/copying the keyrstore file between the PCs ?

No, sorry.

Comment: I ended up getting this to work only after making sure to copy both debug.keystore AND default.keyset. Makes sense for the set up, but just wanted to point this out to others!

Comment: Any idea how to go with option #2 when the second machine is the Android device itself using the AIDE app?  I can't find a `debug.keystore` file anywhere under `/data/data/com.aide.ui`.

Comment: @Michael: I haven't used AIDE. They have to be signing the apps, and so there should be a keystore somewhere, but I wouldn't know where. Sorry!